# Jsp Project run On Nuxeo IDE

Tags: integrate, nuxeo

I have web application project in JSP. I run this project using tomcat server.Now I want to integrate that project in Nuxeo platform with Nuxeo server.what I will do?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a JEE project made with JSP files that you want to run on the same tomcat instance that serves Nuxeo.

As it is a Tomcat server, you just have to deploy you WAR file into the `$NUXEO_HOME/webapps/` folder as you would on a regular Tomcat.

If you want to run your JSP into the nuxeo webapp instance, then you have to package it as a Nuxeo bundle and use `deployment-fragment.xml` file to copy your JSP in the Nuxeo nuxeo.war folder.

First choice will give you a regular JEE app deployment. Your app is isolated from Nuxeo.

Second choice allows you to call Java Nuxeo services from your app.

Comment: I did this but it's not working.I don't understand what write in deployment-fragment.xml file